# How to debug installation of Workload-Scheduler done with IBM Installation Manager?

Tags: installation, workload-scheduler, ibm-installation-manager

I'm working on the installation of Workload-Scheduler, which is done through IBM Installation Manager. I need to stop the installation manager for debugging purpose before the end of the installation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Modify the log.properties of IM (Usually in C:\ProgramData\IBM\InstallationManager\logs) with the properties described below.
- Open IM from command line using IBMIMc.exe and not IBMIM.exe, otherwise these options have no effect.

Sample of  log.properties:

*InstallOperation=DEBUG
InstallOperation/pause.after=install:com.ibm.tws.agent.windows..com.ibm.tws.agent.windows.deployagentwin64:zip:2
InstallOperation/pause.on_error=true
com.ibm.tws=DEBUG*

This allow to block the installation after the unzip of the agent just before the execution of twsinst, so it is possible to modify the agent files on the fly and let the installation to go.

Another example to block the installation at the very beginning:

*InstallOperation/pause.before=pre_install_configure:com.ibm.tws.tdwb.unix..com.ibm.tws.tdwb.unix.definehelpvariables:invoke*

The option:

*InstallOperation/pause.on_error=true*

Cause the IM stop if there is an error. To restart IM you should hit enter in the command line window where you started IBMIMc.exe.
In the same window entries in the log are displayed in the command line window